# Image is not displaying in second activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, photo, photo-gallery

When I click, button gallery opens and I select image, but image is not showing in second Activity.
I am trying from few days but I didn't get result. Please help me with the full code.
Here is my code:

Activity 1

````
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class HomepageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
        ImageButton buttonLoadImage = findViewById(R.id.btnphoto);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                gallery.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(gallery, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }

        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                if (selectedImage != null) {
                    Intent gallery = new Intent(HomepageActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("image", selectedImage.toString());
                    gallery.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(gallery);

                }
            }
        }
}}```

Activity 2
````

Public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

````
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = extras.getString("image");
    Uri imageFinal=Uri.parse(name);

}}```
````

Comment: Well what happens instead? You are doing noting with imageFinal. Please show also.

Comment: You are not showing how you are displaying it. On the side startActivityForResult is deprecated, have a look at Activity Result API.

Comment: I am new to android development. i am not getting what you are all saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageActivity onCreate method

```
  ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.gallery_image);

   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(bundle != null) {
       String uriString = bundle.getString("image");
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
       try {
           imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeUri(this,uri, 300));
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

decodeUri is a example method(working code only) to resize the image convert to bitmap and set to imageview. if the image size is big you might get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(168709632bytes) bitmap.`

```
public static Bitmap decodeUri(Context c, Uri uri, final int requiredSize)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o);

    int width_tmp = o.outWidth
            , height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;

    while(true) {
        if(width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o2);
}
```

activity_gallery_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GalleryImageActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gallery_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

change if statemtemt in onActivityResult

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE)
```

Comment: I think you can accept and upvote the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I did but i have less than 15 reputations so it won't show publicly . I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the image to byte array and then pass that to next activity(as ByteArray) and use that.